What would happen today if a spacecraft failed in orbit with astronauts inside?
Some spaceship - like a Dragon, a Soyuz or a Starliner - leaves the ISS and is doing the orbital maneuvers needed to land where it wants to. And, at this point... they have a problem. The spacecraft propulsion system stops working and there is no way to fix it by remote commands. It remains on the orbit where the failure occurred.
What would happen?
As far as I know the only way to save the astronauts is if another spaceship - either from the ISS or from the Earth - is launched, docks to the stranded spaceship, gets the astronauts out and then it comes back.
Is there any plan for this type of failure? Imagine the nightmare listening to the astronauts as their air supply slowly runs out.

Reading just the title I had a completely different image in my mind what this question was about.

@StevePemberton I tried to explain a scenario that a propulsion failure makes the craft impossible to alter its orbit, i.e. it can not land. Probably a native English speaker had formulated it differently. If you know, how to formulate it well, please click "edit" :-)

I see that the votes came in for changing the title from "on orbit" to "in orbit". It's an often debated topic with a variety of opinions, as seen in this discussion in English Stack Exchange


The thing stops working and there is no way to fix it by remote commands. It remains on the orbit, where it was at the failure.

The plan is for this not to be possible, not to have a response to this scenario.
Even the failures that led to Starliner not being trusted to bring crew home only temporarily disabled a subset of the thrusters needed for it to maneuver. Critical functions of the spacecraft like "being able to maneuver" are protected from total failure by things like multiple-redundancy.

Afaik the simplest way to save the astronauts, if another spaceship - either from the ISS or from the Earth - is launched, docks to the wreck, gets the astronauts out and then it comes back.

No current spacecraft have docking adapters sufficiently androgynous to dock to each other.  The IDSS-equipped spacecraft could get close, but the ports on Starliner and Dragon are active-only and can't dock with each other. They also lack relative navigation targets (like the International Space Station provides) for doing sufficiently precise relative maneuvering to come into contact with each other.  Presumably this will have to get fixed for Artemis HLS, which will have to dock with Gateway and also have Orion dock with it, but even for the presumably-able-to-rendezvous-with-each-other HLS, waiting for a rescue HLS won't be the plan.

Even if a spacecraft had rendezvous capability, (and the supplies to wait on-orbit,) there surely aren't many scenarios where you can't re-enter but can rendezvous safely. For instance if your RCS isn't able to stabilize you enough to land, it can't stabilize you enough to dock either. Maybe a heat shield failure?

@Cadence that sounds ripe for a sci-fi short:  you've clogged your entire prop system with astronauts, can't maneuver, but you can rig up a magnetic detorquer or something to at least knock your rates down to zero.  ...I think there used to be Orion studies on non-cooperative docking with the ISS where the ISS didn't have zero rates, back in the CEV days, but I can't remember what they were called. ADIOS was the other direction, where CEV needed to escape an out-of-control ISS. I don't remember what the rate limits were; obviously it's not going to take a lot before you can't dock.

@ErinAnne during STS-86 training in a period of time when the Mir was losing attitude control a lot, the crew did some (unofficial) testing in the Shuttle Mission Simulator to see what kind of rates an uncontrolled Mir could have and still let them be able to dock. That was fun. And the answer was, not very high rates at all.

@OrganicMarble Rogue System was a delightful, if somewhat fancifully sci-fi, study-level space sim until the sole developer was badly injured. One of the canned missions was to dock with the exterior of a ring-shaped satellite spinning around its axis of symmetry. In 2017 I recorded an almost-90-minute-long video attempting that mission to show it off to a friend. It didn't offer many of the niceties that the Space Shuttle DAP offered aside from some stability modes that helped with cross-coupling, so you end up translating down/up while reversing in.

@ErinAnne Docking into rotating space stations... uhm... I do it normally that I navigate to the rotation axis and start to rotate the ship with the same angular velocity. On this way, it would be like a docking into a non-rotating space station. But it is the hardest part... I think, rotating space stations where the dock connector is not on the rotation axis, only computers could dock.

@peterh I mean, I literally just linked a video where I did exactly what you think only computers could do.  Maybe it's not a great simulation, but like you said, I had the relevant rotation rate (pitch) basically matching the rotation rate of the docking port and was flying the translation by hand.  It's not simple but if I (a low-time instrument-rated commercial pilot and aerospace engineer) can do it, a trained astronaut definitely could.

Btw, it surprises me a little bit - as I can remember, there were already orbital randezvous between USA and Soviet aircrafts already in the 70s. Looks this feature was somehow lost.
